# What to do after editing an answer that was deleted from the review queue?

Tags: discussion

I [answered](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/95679/271) a question, which was put in the low quality review queue.  I don't agree that it was low quality (and [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029) seems to me to agree with me), but I edited it anyway (having thought of what I considered a reasonable compromise between brevity and simplicity)

Now what?  It's been deleted (with a net rep of -1), undelete says mod did it and I can't undelete.  Flagging a mod seems like the wrong thing to do, as does posting my revised answer as a new answer.  Just let it go? While some of the other answers agree in principle, IMO none of them are as clear (or touch upon an issue in my revised answer).

Comment: As to why one-word answers are viewed as low-quality here, check out [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others), as well as some of the links there.

Comment: Related - https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/511/2322

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: **Flag it for moderator attention.** Start a meta thread if you disagree with the mod team's original decision or their response to your flag.

---

Your original answer was:

> No.
>
> (Stackexchange wants more characters, I think the above is sufficient).

The fact that SE wants more characters is a clear sign that you should be writing more, especially on a site like ours where there usually is no one correct answer and you're expected to back up your answers somehow and at the very least explain why something is a certain way. DCON summarised it well in his comment: "*Even though I completely agree with your answer, you need to expand on the why. This answer is incomplete.*"

You ignored the comments explaining the problems inherent in giving an answer like this. Your one-word answer got flagged and was unanimously deleted. You could have clarified the reasoning behind your answer before that. You can contest a deletion as a result of a review queue but typically there's some expectation that you address the problems the post has first or that the result of the reviews was incorrect. You obviously believed the latter but the community disagreed which is why I decided to uphold the decision of the review queue. I commented the following at the time:

> "I think the above is sufficient." I disagree, as does the LQ review queue which unanimously elected to remove this answer as not meeting site standards. Since this hasn't been edited to add further detail I'm upholding the review decision and removing this.

It's only after that that you edited your post but as you saw there's no direct way for you to get your post back on the page. That's why it's useful to consider whether the feedback your post gets is worth acting on or not. And for future reference, adding comments like "*For anyone wondering, I spent a lot of time on the above answer.*" is not the best plan if you want a site community to accept a low-effort one-word answer.

> Now what? It's been deleted (with a net rep of -1), undelete says mod did it and I can't undelete.  Flagging a mod seems like the wrong thing to do,

Nope, that's the best way to proceed in this situation. Simply flag your answer with some variation of "*I edited this answer to improve it and believe the deletion is not / no longer warranted.*".

Alternatively you can start a meta question like you've done here or ask people in the chatroom for input. You can also usually find a few moderators in the chat that you can ping, though flagging is more efficient if you want to reach us.

> as does posting my revised answer as a new answer.

Yeah, you should usually never do that. If you radically changed a post and the original was very badly received you can consider reposting to "start from scratch" but it's often frowned upon. Never do it if you haven't drastically changed your post.

Based on your edits I've reversed the deletion. I've also edited your post slightly to clean up the formatting. A spoiler tag is available cross-network but probably shouldn't be used for cases like this. If you feel this gives an increased impact to your original one-word answer then you can go ahead and edit it back in though.

Comment: I do disagree with decision, while "the community" voted to deleted, I had almost as many upvotes as down(+4/-5) at the point of your deletion.  The **question** was whether using too few words meant that the answer  could be ignored at best or considered a flat out lie at worst.  A long answer **supports** the idea that an answer to a question should be judged on it's length, not on it's correctness. My first comment on the length of my post was not meant as a defense of it's length, but intended for the OP -- as counter to the idea that because it was short, I didn't give any consideration

Comment: to it.  I did, it took me a long time work my way down to just one word.  As for what should happen if there was an alternate answer that was just "Yes", the community should vote.  Frankly I think the ideal situation for this question would be for there to be just two answers yes/no, with votes and comments.  There is one answer that is yes, it has (at this time) 4 upvotes.  There are 18 other answers that are no, the top voted answer has 206 upvotes.  Combine all of the upvotes on no and compare it to the yes votes and you'd see that there is no question that a long answer is not necessary.

Comment: "*Frankly I think the ideal situation*" I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this site works. As I mentioned, this is not a technical site where we have correct answers. We answer interpersonal questions and cover workplace situations where virtually nothing is ever black-and-white. By your logic I could have simply answered your question here with "Flag it." You'd have no idea why you should or what else you could try but it'd be an answer coming from someone with a diamond next to their name so therefore it would surely have to be correct,

Comment: just like the Yes/No answer would be decided simply by virtue of the votes. But that's not how any of this works. We explicitly mark questions that are a simple "tell me what to do" as off-topic. There are a variety of reasons for that but the main one is that it simply doesn't make for good Q&A. "Yes you should" tells me or others *nothing* about the reasons behind that decisions, and that's what we're all about here.

Comment: Answers shouldn't tell someone what to do but how they should make a decision, what options are available to them and which might be ideal for in a particular situation because of X, Y and Z. As for the votes: you got 6 delete votes and several downvotes initially with those upvotes coming in after you undeleted it initially. They're presumably the result of the HNQ influx with a lot of users who aren't accustomed to our site culture and who tend to upvote but never downvote. And even if that wasn't the case the delete votes cast by high-rep users tend to carry more weight in this process.